# Repairing an old Bench Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, constant-current, voltage-source

I have an old PS-303D from Conrad in use at home. Recently it showed a problem.

If I measure with my multi from V- to V+, the voltage reading is correct, current and voltage regulation seems to work fine. But when I connect V- with GND the supply turns off. Connecting V+ with GND is no problem. So I opened the case and did a little check ups. Soldering looks so far ok, and no visible damage has occurred. The GND is only connected to the case and via 2 ceramic capacitors to V+ and V- which seem ok. I looked at the schematic and I understand what each section is doing, but after a day of measuring I can't seem to find the error.

Can anyone point me to the right direction on how to approach the problem? Help would be greatly appreciated.

[Schematic](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/361907/510077-sp-01-en-Power_Supply_PS_303_Pro.pdf):

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Are you sure the 2 ceramic capacitors are OK. Try disconnecting them and see if the problem goes away.  From your description it appears that the capacitor from V+ to GND may be shorted.  This would not cause a problem when V+ is connected to GND but would create a short between V+ and V- when the V- terminal is connected to GND.

Comment: It's possible you already have a (partial) short from V+ to GND. C405 Maybe.

Comment: Also check any power elements which are heatsinked to the chassis, one may  have an electrical short to the case

Comment: @Barry I completly desoldered C405, C406 and C402... The problem persists.

Comment: @JoeySsymank I wonder what you found out. If there was a solution, please answer your own question - by posting an answer, not editing the question of course. It'd help others who may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think sstobbe is on the right track here - something in the supply likely has a “sneak path” to the chassis. I would start troubleshooting this by connecting a high value resistor (100 k perhaps) between the minus output and the chassis ground. That shouldn’t make the supply turn off and you can measure the voltage across the resistance- check for both AC and DC voltage. Since there shouldn’t be any voltage the amount may give you a hint of where the problem may be.

You can also unplug the supply, make sure it is *fully* discharged and use an ohmmeter to check the resistance between various points of the board and chassis- they should all be high resistance (of course take the resistor mentioned above off first).

Comment: This would make sense, since when I touch the cables with bare hands the current sense LED glows dim. I will try this and report back...